# MeasureIt / Blender 2.8 : black screen with only measures, how to render?

Tags: rendering

I tried eeVee & cycles, same result. Normal render (F12) works well but obviously without measures.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.80, the add-on generates the measures in a separate image. The final image is done through the compositor as below (before rendering as usual, F12).

[image]